# JavaScript code does not work in HEAD tag

Tags: javascript, html, head

My webpage has the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is test Page</title>
    
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = document.URL.toString();
        </script>
   
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="sss">
        <p id="msg1"></p>
    </div>

     
</body>
</html>
```

As you may know, at the time the script executes the div doesn't exist. I want to put my JavaScript code only In the `<head>` tag and I won't put it in middle of HTML code.

But this code only works when I put the `<script>` tag after the `<div>` tag.
I use VS2010 and firefox 19.0.1

Is there anyway to put code in `<head>` tag?

Comment: No element exists at that point.

Comment: The body loads after the head. Hence the script in your head is not able to find the element in your body. Place your script tag at the end of your body or wait for the onload event fired on the body to execute the code.

Comment: Exactly. The time the script executes the div doesn't exist. Try coupling a mechanism such as calling the script on hovering the div element or may be a button that explicitly says "get the URL". You either maintain the order or call your script in a particular event.

Comment: @elclanrs: i know but i want Put all javascript code in HEAD tag

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your script relies on the DOM being ready, so you need to execute that function call only after the DOM is ready.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = document.URL.toString();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The various tags in your HTML page are loaded and processed in the order in which they appear on the page. Your `<script>` tag is executed immediately when it is parsed in the `<head>`. This is before the `<body>` and the elements inside the `<body>` are parsed. So, the script tries to reference an element that is not defined at the time it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Geary is right, in order to execute your code, I'd use jQuery library (a de-facto standard in JS development) and utilize the DOM ready event. This will ensure the code in the handler will execute once DOM is fully loaded.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#msg1').html(document.URL.toString());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: tnx for jQuery but i want to use javascript itself...not third-party library....but if One time I wanted use jQuery in my page certainly i use your code!

Comment: Now that it's 2018, all modern browsers support the document `ready` event. So no need to use jQuery for this any more.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to to use `addEventListener` like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => { 
       document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = document.URL.toString();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can u explain more??

Comment: o catch the loading of the document with nodes I would advise you to use DOMContentLoaded, while  window.onload, for example, is triggered only after every image have finished loading, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your script uses dom element and must run after the dom loaded.

Wrap your code in a function and call it after dom loaded

```
function myfunc(){  
//code here
}
window.onload = myfunc();
```

Comment: `window.onload = myfunc;` don't have `()` when assigning an event handler

Answer (score 0):

This is test Page

```
 <script defer language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = document.URL.toString();
    </script>
```