# Problem with attaching a click event to a button using a external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to attach a click or onlclick event to a button element through external JavaScript but it is not working. Can anyone help? I am writing my code below for reference.
Html part:-

```
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">ClickMe</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>    
</body>
```

JS code :-

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript code not work in HEAD tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675745/javascript-code-not-work-in-head-tag)

Comment: Your issue is related to loader of the DOM loading. See the above - the fact your code is external is not a factor here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait DOM loading elements.

Def script after html tags.
**Solution 1:**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="myBtn">ClickMe</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>    
  <!--Put script tag in end of body-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Other solution use onload function . In onload call DOM is loaded and ready for access.
**Solution 2:**

```
// SCRIPT
window.onload = function() {

 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
 }

 document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

};

<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="myBtn">ClickMe</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>    
</body>
```

Try it :

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```

```html
 
 <button id="myBtn">ClickMe</button>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Solution 1 isn't valid HTML when it's outside of the body - it would be fine if you put it within the body, at the end.

Comment: Is not necessary... Its is a still in <html>

Comment: Implementing things to standard is entirely necessary. The difference to you is moving up a line and it would actually make your answer correct to the widely accepted standards. Unsure why the push back here.

Answer (score -1):

Add the script tag after the HTML It will surely solve your problem

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">ClickMe</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>    
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it doesn't work because the load order around the DOM in a conventional web page. It only works in the snippet viewer as the load order isn't emulated correctly.

Comment: My bad. He put the script before the HTML code and the HTML portion was not loaded properly.

Comment: The edit looks good, welcome to Stack Overflow! +1.