# Graphs - Implementing ordered, asynchronous script loads?

Tags: javascript, head.js

To increase performance there are many ways to load JavaScript asynchronously as shown in this [SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396849/does-the-script-tag-position-in-html-affects-performance-of-the-webpage)

However, in general, these methods do not preserve the ordering if you need it, say for dependencies.

In what ways can you get the benefit of asynchronous loading but also preserving ordering when needed.

Backbone dependencies are a good example.

(require.js, jquery.js) -> backbone.js

Is there an implementation of promises or queues available from libraries that accomplish this?

It does not look like [head.js](http://headjs.com/) uses promises or queues yet.

Comment: How about [JQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution: Use [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises). [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in jQuery provides promises as of version 1.5.

If you can't use third-party libraries, you can do something like this:

```
var resourceData = {};
var resourcesLoaded = 0;

function loadResource(resource, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var state = this.readyState;
        var responseCode = request.status;

        if(state == this.DONE && responseCode == 200) {
            callback(resource, this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("get", resource, true);
    xhr.send();
}

//Assuming that resources is an array of path names
function loadResources(resources) {
    for(var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        loadResource(resources[i], function(resource, responseText) {

            //Store the data of the resource in to the resourceData map,
            //using the resource name as the key. Then increment the
            //resource counter.
            resourceData[resource] = responseText;
            resourcesLoaded++;

            //If the number of resources that we have loaded is equal
            //to the total number of resources, it means that we have
            //all our resources.
            if(resourcesLoaded === resources.length) {
                //Manipulate the data in the order that you desire.
                //Everything you need is inside resourceData, keyed
                //by the resource url. 
                ...
                ...
            }                    
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @livingston_mechanical If you fire off multiple async requests, there is no guarantee as to when each request will complete. Do you want to resolve dependencies as each one has finished loading, or after they all have finished loading?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Do you know the dependency tree before hand?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical I've updated my answer. You can fire off all requests, but defer the actual work until everything has been loaded.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical No, unfortunately. But you can look at n-ary/generic trees, since that's basically what a dependency tree is.  I have a Java implementation [here](https://github.com/vivin/GenericTree) that might help. But you probably don't even need to deal with a dependency tree in your solution; you can fire off all requests one after the other and then wait until they are all done, before you do any work.

Comment: ...coming back to this, I think DAG / Adjacency list is more relevant.  I'll post a solution once I have it.

Comment: Yes, you can then do a topological sort and load dependencies in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing and using the Combres library.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/combres

Loading order is only one of many benefits. Minification, css variables, tilda use in paths (like in asp.net), etc, etc are just some of the benefits, as well as combining and caching.

Comment: Whatever order you put them in, in the configuration, is the order they are loaded. You can have groups as well.

Comment: It's up to you to place your scripts in the order of your requirements. You can create groups of CSS and JS files and load them as needed. But for my current project, we have decided to load all required CSS and JS files, whether the actual page needs it or not. That way, the hit is only on the first page load, they are then compressed, minimized, and cached into a single CSS and JS resource file. The application, through Combres, then used the cached files instead of reloading all of them on each request. It's a well done plug-in and fairly easy to implement.