# HTMLService won't display return value

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a sidebar to have a basic UI for searching my Google sheet. I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) exactly to make sure the first step works, except that it doesn't! I even took out the userObject part to make it simpler (honestly, because I don't know what that part does).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function updateButton(email, button) {
        button.value = 'Clicked by ' + email;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          //.withUserObject(this)
          .testMe()" />
    <input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          //.withUserObject(this)
          .testMe()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

It calls this function:

```
function testMe() {
  Logger.log("Test log.");
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Jackpot!");
}
```

If it matters, the HTML runs in a sidebar via onOpen as follows:

```
function showGradingSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testSidebar')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Testing Module')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

When I click the button, it does nothing (that I can see). By changing various aspects, I can get it to Logger.log() a simple message but even that doesn't work reliably if I change the HTML side.

I was reading about the security restrictions that require sanitizing what the function returns, but both HtmlService.createHtmlOutput() and ContentService.createTextOutput() were also unsuccessful. Please advise.

UPDATE: Thanks to @Bryan P, I got it to work. The testMe() is simply:

```
return "Jackpot";
```

...and the HTML page looks like this:

```
[html, head, etc.]<body>
    <input type="button" value="Ready"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
          .withUserObject(this)
          .testMe()" --->
  <br><div id="output">Output goes here: </div>
  <br><div id="papa">Papa goes here: </div>
  <br><p></p>
  <script>
    function updateButton(result) {
      var div = document.getElementById('output')
      div.innerHTML = 'It finally works!' + result;
    }
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how much it helped, but I did move the script tag down to the bottom of the body, fwiw, after reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396849/does-the-script-tag-position-in-html-affects-performance-of-the-webpage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, if you right-click in the sidebar area >> Inspect >> in the Console it should show a message that there wasn't a valid return type after clicking on one of the buttons.

`.createTextOutput(content)` returns a TextOutput type (which isn't the same as just plain text type)

It's only used when you've deployed a the web app URL and some external service calls that URL. It only gets [handled with doGet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) too.

Did you try just `return "Jackpot";` instead?

`.withUserObject(this)` - `this` refers to button element and the whole method passes it on to the `successHandler()`. So you can consider keeping it. Otherwise you'd have to reference the button from within the successHandler another way:

```
function updateButton(email) {
  document.getElementById('myButton').value = 'Clicked by ' + email;
}
```

...which requires you add an ID attribute into the button.

You can always do:

```
function updateButton(email, button) {
  console.log('Success hit');
  button.value = 'Clicked by ' + email;
}
```

...to check whether the successHandler was even called in that Chrome dev console too.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I guess I was misusing the Content Service then. I did try plain `return "Jackpot"` first before I found out about the security restrictions, so then I didn't know what was a "dirty" return or not.

I finally got it to work after an hour implementing Bryan's input. I updated my original post for posterity.